# how to run a script start-up on live distro?

Tags: startup, live-usb

I'm using a live distro installed on usb drive (persistence mode)

Is any way to run a script automatically when machine starts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at `cron`. It can do exactly what you're after and will be installed on just about any base install.